# upgraded ruby and still shows an older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I had installed ruby by

```
rvm upgrade 2.7.1
```

and yet, when I try to bundle install, I get

Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.7.0

when issuing

```
which ruby
```

I get :

/Users/saraginsburg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby

any ideas on how to solve this will be highly appreciated.

thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Did you read the RVM documentation at https://rvm.io/? It describes all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading installs the new version, but you may need to *use* it, as in:

```
rvm use --default 2.7.1
```

Where the `--default` flag pins it for future shells.

Also check for `.ruby-version` which may cause it to switch within that directory.

You can check which version is active and which are available with:

```
rvm list
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose the correct version of Ruby for your project. Try to run `rvm use 2.7.1` or create a file '.ruby-version' in your project root that contains the version number `2.7.1`.